# Youtube logo (used in my homepage) has an unexpected underline at the right bottom corner?

Tags: html, css, youtube, graphical-logo

I am ceating a simple homepage and there I used youtube logo to put a connection link. But the logo has an unexpected mark (I highlighted it with marker in my attachment) below. What's wrong with my html code? 
Check the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y3bj3kpu/).

Also how to move the "find me on" paragraph little bit left of it? [Attachment](https://s.yimg.com/hd/answers/i/5adb529aad0d409981a41ba76525ad63_A.jpeg?a=answers&mr=0&x=1408653864&s=0cd46387459ff66f0ee307ee1089e481)

I pasted my HTML and CSS code below:

.HTML file:

```
 <img src="about_me_modified.PNG" width="80%" height="50%"/> 

<p id="find_me_on"><br /><br />Find me on:<br><br><a href="https://www.facebook.com/zabirfatah"><img src="fblogo.PNG" /></a><br><a href="https://twitter.com/jabirfatah91"><img src="twitterlogo.PNG" /></a><br><a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/jabirfatah"><img src="youtubelogo.PNG" />
</a><br><a href="https://plus.google.com/100402704740320621129/about"><img src="googleplus-logo.PNG" /></a><br><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/pub/jabir-al-fatah/5b/50b/2b1"><img src="linkedinlogo.PNG" />
</a></p>
```

.CSS file:

```
    #find_me_on{
float:right;
margin-right:20px;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underline was actually an `a` tag not being formatted corectly, because anchors are inline elements. If you add:

```
a{
   display:block;
}
```

to your CSS and remove the `<br>`s then you get this [**result**](http://jsfiddle.net/imtheman/y3bj3kpu/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below. The line is because of the new line space be end of the `img` tag and the end of the `a` tag. You could wrap the `a` tag section in a `div`.

```
<img src="about_me_modified.PNG" width="80%" height="50%"/> 

<p id="find_me_on">
    <br /><br />Find me on:
    <div class="find_links">
        <br>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/zabirfatah"><img src="fblogo.PNG" /></a>
        <br>
        <a href="https://twitter.com/jabirfatah91"><img src="twitterlogo.PNG" /></a>
        <br>
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/jabirfatah"><img src="youtubelogo.PNG" /></a>
        <br>
        <a href="https://plus.google.com/100402704740320621129/about"><img src="googleplus-logo.PNG" /></a>
        <br>
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/pub/jabir-al-fatah/5b/50b/2b1"><img src="linkedinlogo.PNG" /></a>
    </div>
</p>

<style>
    #find_me_on{
        float:right;
        margin-right:20px;
    }

    #find_me_on div.find_links {
        padding-left: 5px;
    }

    #find_me_on div.find_links a {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
</style>
```